# Query GPU memory usage and/or user by PID

Tags: bash, cuda, nvidia-smi

I have a list of PIDs of processes running on different GPUs. I want to get the used GPU memory of each process based on its PID. `nvidia-smi` yields the information I want; however, I don't know how to grep it, as the output is sophisticated. I have already looked for how to do it, but I have not found any straightforward answers.

Comment: You can make the output less sophisticated. E.g. `nvidia-smi --query-compute-apps=pid,used_memory --format=csv,noheader,nounits`

Comment: @paleonix Hello, thank you, actually, the command you provided helped me a lot! Maybe make a full answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the default output of `nvidia-smi` is "sophisticated" or rather formatted for interfacing with humans rather than scripts, the command provides lots of options for use in scripts. The ones most fitting for use case seem to be `--query-compute-apps=pid,used_memory` specifying the information that you need and `--format=csv,noheader,nounits` specifying the minimal, machine readable output formatting.

So the resulting command is

```
nvidia-smi --query-compute-apps=pid,used_memory --format=csv,noheader,nounits
```

I recommend taking a look at `man nvidia-smi` for further information and options.

Answer (score 0):

```
nvidia-smi  --query-compute-apps=pid,used_memory,gpu_bus_id --format=csv
```

gpu_bus_id will help you if you have multiple gpus